# How to put an NSView below the titlebar in a NSViewController?

Tags: macos, cocoa

My app architecture is as follows: **MainWindowController** init with **MainWindow**, after initialization **MainWindowController** create a **MainViewController** and assign it to the **contentViewController**
property.

Now I want to add some controls in **MainViewController**. When I put an **NSTextFiled** using **AutoLayout** at the top of the viewcontroller, the textField is shaded by the titlebar of the **MainWindow**. How can I add a constraint to locate the textField just below the titlebar (in iOS, I can use **topLayoutGuide**)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: when I init the **MainWindow**, I use the **fullSizeContentView** flag. After removing the flag everything works perfectly.